# How to test prop function that changes other prop Jest Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that receives value 'openDrawer' (bool) and function 'toggleDrawerHandler' in props, the function 'toggleDrawerHandler' changes the value of 'openDrawer' prop.
I would like to test it by simulating a click on div that triggers this function, and check if the component change when the value of 'openDrawer' changes.

The component

```
const NavigationMobile = (props) => {
  const { openDrawer, toggleDrawerHandler } = props;
  let navClass = ["Nav-Mobile"];
  if (!openDrawer) navClass.push("Close");
  return (
    <div className="Mobile">
      <div className="Menubar" onClick={toggleDrawerHandler}>
        {openDrawer ? <FaTimes size="1.5rem" /> : <FaBars size="1.5rem" />}
      </div>
      <nav className={navClass.join(" ")} onClick={toggleDrawerHandler}>
        <Navigation />
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The component that sends these props

```
const Header = (props) => {
  const [openDrawer, setOpenDrawer] = useState(false);

  const toggleDrawerHandler = () => {
    setOpenDrawer((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  return (
    <header className="Header">
      <NavigationMobile openDrawer={openDrawer} toggleDrawerHandler={toggleDrawerHandler} />
    </header>
  );
};
```

my test, but doesn't work

```
  it("changes prop openDrawer when click", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<NavigationMobile />);
    expect(wrapper.find("FaBars")).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(wrapper.find("nav").hasClass("Nav-Mobile")).toBeTruthy();

    wrapper.find(".Menubar").simulate("click", true); // doesnt work

    expect(wrapper.find("FaTimes")).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(wrapper.find("nav").hasClass("Nav-Mobile Close")).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: How do you know if it doesn't work without checking the `toggleDrawerHandler`'s number of calls?

Comment: Your test is supposed to be something like `shallow(<NavigationMobile toggleDrawerHandler={yourJestSpyToCheckCall}  />); `

Comment: that is the thing, I dont know if I should pass a mock function as a prop in place of toggleDrawerHandler that returns true?

Comment: Just create the simple spy one `const toggleSpy = jest.fn()`. Makes sense?

Comment: const toggleDrawerHandlerMock = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<NavigationMobile openDrawer={false} toggleDrawerHandler={toggleDrawerHandlerMock} />);
    expect(wrapper.find("FaBars")).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(wrapper.find("nav").hasClass("Nav-Mobile")).toBeTruthy();
    wrapper.find(".Menubar").simulate("click");
    expect(toggleDrawerHandlerMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // this is ok but it does not change value of openDrawer prop

Comment: Congrats! it's working :)

Comment: I am new in testing, so maybe I dont understand, but shouldn't I try to change the value of prop openDrawer to see the changes on component? I thought it is good thing to test

Comment: Of course since you have 2 cases against your prop. I think snapshots is a good way to go to cache the tree in 2 cases